# How to configure Qt debugger and what is needed for it to work

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Ok so Im really confused here, I got the same erroe as Martin.kv who started this thread [How to configure CDB in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975949/how-to-configure-cdb-in-qt-creator/12057804#12057804)

which said "The preferred debugger engine for debugging binaries of type 'x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit' is not available....Details: There is no CDB binary available for binaries in format 'x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit"

I assume I have to download some stuff to fix this, so I went here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx and I have Windows 7 on a 32-bit system so I went under this title "Install the Windows 7 Version of Debugging Tools for Windows" and went here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279 to download the Debugging tools for windows.

From all the stuff I've read, on the thread I referenced and a few others, what I downloaded seemed to be the right thing.

I admit I screwed up a little because I forgot to check where it was putting the Debugger Tools because while it started downloading I was still searching for what to do after the download. But I'm pretty sure it is in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit" but I dont have anything called Windows Kits, which everyone else is saying theirs is in, and I still dont seem to have a cdb.exe..

did I download the wrong thing? What do I need to do/download instead? and also where can I get the Symbol Server that the Qt site and many other people suggest??

Sorry I'm new to Qt and some what to programming in general and my program for my internship is due at the end of the day and last night it stopped working so I'm kind of freaking out a little but I figure the debugger could help because it doesnt really make sense why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a place in the Qt Creator settings where you can point it to the cdb.exe that comes with the Debugging tools for Windows.

See here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-debugger-engines.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response rebenvb. I about setting the Creator to pint to the cdb.exe but the problem is that I havent been able to find the cbd.exe.. Did I download the right thing?

Comment: @Gary: check `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows`.

Comment: ...wow! I promise you I'm not a complete idiot. I didn't see it so I even searched for it and got nothing but its exactly where you said.

What about the Symbols thing that I keep seeing people say to download? Do I need that and where can I get it?

Comment: Well never mind I guess, when I ran the Debugger after pointing it to the right place it asked if I wanted to set the Symbol thing up

Comment: yeah, Windows search can be flaky. And the Microsoft Symbol Servers give you debug symbols for system (and Visual Studio) DLLs, which is handy when looking at backtraces.

Answer (score 0):

I got cdb working with QtCreator only after the following steps: 
1) Download & install Debugging Tools for Windows
2) QtCreator->Tools->Options->Build & Run->Tool Chains
3) Copy autodetected MS compiler to the "manual" section
4) Set the path to cdb.exe
5) Use the "manual" MS compiler.

Perhaps there's some way to avoid steps 3-5 (playing around with environment variables maybe) but the described scheme works fine so I don't mind.