# CDB debugger for MSCV17 on Qt not working

Tags: windows, qt, debugging, visual-c++

I am running Qt5.11.1 with the MSCV2017 32bit compiler. For debugging I have the CDB x86 and everything compiles and runs well.

The problem is with the debugger. When I run it, it behaves like it's a normal run. So my program just starts, but doesn't stop at breakpoints or any other debugger related thing. It looks like it's freezing: [image]

So I cannot pause, step over etc. and it only shows that it's starting..forever. 
I have seen several people who complained about the CDB being slow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957158/qt-creator-debug-mode-is-really-slow), [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33002-Debugging-extremely-slow) and [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-September/024176.html), there is also a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18287) about it.), but mine is not working *at all!*

Does anyone have any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: What's the specific reason for using CDB in this context?

Comment: I am using the MSCV compiler, so I need the CDB compiler for it. (That's what I learned at least.) @IInspectable

Comment: CDB is not required to debug a Qt application in Visual Studio. You can use Visual Studio's debugger.

Comment: @IInspectable I am compiling in Qt application _in Qt_ with MSCV compiler, so CDB is the only option as far as I know.

Comment: So you are using Qt Creator? If you do, and you are using the Visual Studio compiler already, there's little reason to not make a full switch to Visual Studio. [Bring your existing Qt projects to Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/14/bring-your-existing-qt-projects-to-visual-studio/) has basic instructions on integrating Qt's build system (qmake), in case that is an issue. None of that addresses the question you asked, so this is posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I am using Qt Creator. Thanks for the suggestion. I guess that might work as well. I will leave it as a last resort if I give up on Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to install a different SDK version and it worked for me.